# Use GUI to compare SVN revision of file with previous revision on Linux

Tags: svn, subclipse

I am trying to browse through the history of a file in SVN and see what changes selected revisions to that file introduced, using Subclipse - much as you can browse the changes to a page on Wikipedia.

I first tried double-clicking on the row in the history, but that didn't work - I got some "file does not exist" error message. As far as I can see with Subclipse, you have to right-click on the revision, find the menu option "Compare...", then click on the second Select button and find the revision immediately before (i.e. below) the one you want to compare to (which is usually but not always highlighted in bold), and then click OK twice, which is a tediously long process. I'm looking for a more convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the item checked out, do Compare with > Revision.  This brings up a compare UI with the list of revisions.  You can just click on each revision to see the differences.  This will compare that revision against what you have checked out.

Alternatively, you can do Team > Show History to see all change to the file.  Select any two revisions, right click and choose the Compare option to see the differences in those revisions.

Finally, when browsing Show History to simply see the change in a specific revision, just select that revision, right click and choose Compare and click OK on the subsequent dialog.  You do not need to change any of the settings in the dialog.

Answer (score -3):

In Emacs:

1. C-x C-f and choose the file to view the history of.
2. C-x v l
3. Tab down to the revision of interest (or click on it)
4. Press capital D to view a diff (for all the files changed by that
   revision)
5. To look at another one, press C-x o and go back to step 3.

Comment: I wrote the question.

Comment: So? The question is for subclipse, not for Emacs.